# Support of "export ... from" by the TypeScript compiler

Tags: typescript, tsc

Is the following `export` supported by the tsc compiler?

```
export {PromiseWrapper, Promise, PromiseCompleter}
              from 'angular2/src/facade/promise';
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. You can have a look at the corresponding section in the TypeScript specification:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#11343-export-list-declarations

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Pleased to hear that ;-) There is something I missed. Importing elements exported like gives me undefined. I think that I need to have a deeper look at the Angular2 build script...